# Appending timestamp to grep output

Tags: bash

i'm trying to append a timestamp to ping output (only the pong time), Also i'm very new to bash scripting so an explanation would be very appreciated (not only the solution)

i've tried

```
sed  "s/$/\ `date +%T`/" instead of the loop
```

Also i know about `"ping -D"` but for learning purposes (adding a timestamp) i rather use an appending solution via sed or a simple loop; and which of the solutions is faster (memory/CPU)

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | grep -Po '(?<=time=)\S+' |  while read -r line; do echo "$line $(date +%T)"; done
```

i'm expecting

```
51.7 12:18:06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

ping 8.8.8.8 | stdbuf -oL grep -Po '(?<=time=)\S+' |
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line $(date +%T)"
done
```

Comment: This works thanks! can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Nothing wrong. The only thing is, grep is buffering its output (because it's not used interactively). To avoid that, here it is called by stdbuf(1), which sets grep output to line-buffered again.

Comment: Ah thank you i'll try to read more on buffers and stdbuf(1). As they say the devil is in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | grep --line-buffered -Po '(?<=time=)\S+' | xargs -Ivals  bash -c 'echo "vals $(date +%T)"'
```

**Example**

```
ping -w6 8.8.8.8 | grep --line-buffered -Po '(?<=time=)\S+'  | xargs -Ivals  bash -c 'echo "vals $(date +%T)"'
23.0 10:12:25
23.0 10:12:26
23.0 10:12:27
23.0 10:12:28
23.0 10:12:29
22.9 10:12:30
```

Comment: This works but for only one line, the aim for my code is to log the output for plotting. can you make it continuous ?

Comment: Ah this one works! thank man i'll try to parse through it to understand it. 
Also isn't --line-buffered only for BSD based systems? because i've read about it and it was mentioned that grep on *nix systems don't need it. any good  articles (with exercises) on buffers and how they work?

Comment: You may refer to this [article](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/).

Comment: Thanks man i'll read it. tried to search some articles but got really confused!